# Dynamo DB - Concurrent Updates

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I need to manage concurrent updates in a Dynamo DB Table. After doing a bit of research, I came across two ways to do the same:

1. > Optimistic Locking through Version IDs - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaVersionSupportHLAPI.html
2. > Conditional Save - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.SpecifyingConditions.html

Are there any more ways to handle concurrent updates in Dynamo DB?

**User Scenario**

`Table A - maintains some kind of state [STARTED, IN_PROGRESS, COMPLETE]`

The change of state can only be like this.

```
STARTED -> IN_PROGRESS 
IN_PROGRESS -> COMPLETE
IN_PROGRESS -> STARTED (back step)
```

I think I can use both optimistic locking and conditional write here.

**Optimistic Locking -**

1. Have a version number. When Thread 1 updates state to IN_PROGRESS, the version number is increased to 1.
2. Next if some Thread 2 changes the state back to STARTED, the version number will be increased to 2.
3. Later if Thread 1 tries to change the state back to COMPLETE it is going to fail since the Versions would differ.

**Conditional Save -**

1. Have a condition to check that when we try to change State to COMPLETE the current state should be IN_PROGRESS and not STARTED.

I think I can use either of the mechanism in this kind of situation. Is that correct? Or are there any specific situations where we should prefer one over the other?

Comment: There is a "transactional" library developed by awslabs [here](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-transactions). What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @mkobit Concurrent updates to tables. Need to make sure that only 1 thread can update the table at a time.

Comment: Only 1 thread can update a table or an item in that table at a time? What kind of updates are you doing (counting, set addition) because you may be able to use something like an [atomic counter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters).

Comment: I think what he meant is that it only appends data based on the list it get at the moment, but not the latest list.